# How to extend /boot which is not on lvm

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a machine with 100 mb boot partition but for installing new kernel with other module it needs additional 50 MB.

How can i extend it its not on LVM.

If i attach new disk and copy whole content of /boot/* to new partition and set that in fstab will it work after reboot?

will MBR contain new fstab entry before it calls grub to load during restart.

I dont want to mess with this server thats why i am confirming this.

using grub2 on ubuntu 12.04